# how to apply IC to solve PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I need to solve this equation

[image]

I know how to solve such equations of the form, $u_t=u_{xx}-au$ using the transformation $$u=e^{-at}w(x,t).$$

But the problem is the the coefficient is in terms of $t$, it is not constant, so i think this transformation wont work.

Can you suggest any hint. I can solve it on my own.

Can this be solved without having any BCs , coz only IC is given.

Answer (score 3):

$$(t+1)u_t-u=(t+1)u_{xx}$$
$$\dfrac {(t+1)u_t-u}{(t+1)^2}=\dfrac {u_{xx}}{t+1}$$
$$\left(\dfrac u {t+1} \right)_t=\left (\dfrac {u}{t+1}\right)_{xx}$$
$$w_t(x,t)=w_{xx}(x,t)$$
Where $w(x,t)=\dfrac {u(x,t)}  {t+1}$

Comment: hey thanks i feel difficulty in solving initial conditions...first of all i dont think this  will involve summation thing in asnwer and it is not giving me non zero solution

Comment: You're welcome the initial conditions dosent change with the change of variable since $w(x,0)=u(x,0)$ @learningstudent

Comment: no i know what u said.....!! i said when i get the solution form in u x,t then applying the initial conditions doesn't give me some solution @aryadeva